# Service Worker Displaying Multiple Notifications

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have used service worker in wordpress to send push notification on new post published but when i publish new post it displays multiple Notifications rather than single.

Below is the code Snippet i used in sw.js

```
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { 
     navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
       if (registrations.length) {
         for (let registration of registrations) {
           registration.unregister();
         }
       }
      });

      var myId = obj.messagingSenderId;
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js?messagingSenderId=' + myId).then(function (reg) {
        console.log("SW registration succeeded. Scope is " + reg.scope);
        messaging.useServiceWorker(reg);
        reg.update();
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error("SW registration failed with error " + err);
      });
    }

    requestPermission();
```

Comment: check your dev console.  I have a feeling that you have multiple service workers installed

Comment: yes I have checked console and in some devices there is multiple Service Workers but i am facing problem in updating service worker programatically.

Comment: one more thing what if there is multiple service workers should we ignore one and count latest service worker to fire action or something like that.